# parse web pages when the main url does not change but the table content does

Tags: javascript, python, css, ajax, parsing

consider [this](http://www.4-traders.com/stock-exchange/shares/Middle-East-5/Saudi-Arabia-108/) url. When next page(s) is selected the table is reloaded with new content but there is no change in the url address. Inspecting the developer tools > Network > XHR also does not seem to identify the source url for new pages loaded. Appreciate help in identifying how i can parse subsequent pages (after the default page) in this situation? thanks you.

Comment: Maybe it's always the same page but with dynamic content, then you need to re-render the content using Javascript.

Comment: What is the result when you select `Network` -> `All`?

Comment: it loads virtually all of the source links but among them i still cannot find source to the table content for that page. I am somewhat novice at this, so not sure, what exactly i should be looking at under Network > All

Comment: Have you checked each resource loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There is ajax request to http://www.4-traders.com/outils/mods_a/moteurs_results.php?ResultMode=7&model=3&undefined which returns table with rows

[image]